# passing arguaments to a system call in Rails, but not plain ruby program

Tags: ruby, sinatra, system

Ubuntu 12.04

Sinatra 1.3.3

Why does passing an argument to a ruby system call (%x[] or ``) give me a 'not found' error in my sinatra app?  The same code works fine in a normal ruby script running from the same directory.

I have a file test.rb like this

```
output = %x["ls"] 
p output
```

When I run it with "ruby test.rb" I get the contents of the current directory in the console, as expected.

If I modify the program to give an argument to the system call like so:

```
output = %x["ls sub_dir/"] 
p output
```

I get the contents of sub_dir, which sits in the current directory, as expected.

So far so good.

Now if I make a Sintra app with a post method:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra'

post "/" do
 output = x["ls"]
 return output
end
```

The response to a Post call to "/" returns the contents of the current directory, which includes 'sub_dir', as expected.

If I try to add the argument to the system call to the sinatra app like so:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra'

post "/" do
 output = x["ls sub_dir/"]
 return output
end
```

the response is nil and there is an error in the console:

> sh: 1: ls sub_dir/: not found

Why does adding a parameter to a system call in my sinatra app cause it to crash, when the same code called from a plain ruby script, run from the same location works perfectly.

By the way, the 'ls' example shown here is not the command I really need to run, so please don't explain a different way to get this information. I have an executable file that takes a file name as a parameter that I need to run, which behaves exactly the same way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to use a fully qualified filename instead of a relative one? The current working directory can change sometimes, especially when you use real hosting. Using full paths makes you mine to these changes and typically also makes your intend much clearer.

Comment: This is a good tip, thanks, but unfortunately, I still have the same problem.  Running  %x['ls /'] gives the same error.  Running  %x['ls -l'] gives the same error.The problem seems to be with trying to pass an argument, not the file location.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the sinatra app in another file in the same directory.

Everything works as expected.

I did not find the reason and I deleted the original file so that I won't lose anymore time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify a path in relation to the application, you could use something like this:

```
post "/" do
 path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "sub_dir")
 %x[ls #{path}]
end
```

However, if you want to list the contents of a directory, why not do it in Ruby?

Comment: This is a good tip, thanks, but unfortunately, I still have the same problem.  In this case path = "./sub_dir/" which gives the same error.  In fact, running  %x['ls -l'] gives the same error.The problem seems to be with trying to pass an argument, not the file location.  Any other ideas?